# How to include only selected embedded document in mongoengine?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine, embedded-documents

I'm fetching documents on the base of specific `EmbeddedDocument`, but I don't want to get all of the `EmbeddedDocuments` while retrieving, only the matched `EmbeddedDocument` with main `Document`.

Here's my code:

**School Embedded Document**

```py
class School(EmbeddedDocument):
    name = StringField(max_length=120)
```

**User Document**

```py
class User(Document):
    first_name = StringField(max_length=60, required=True)
    last_name = StringField(max_length=60)
    schools = EmbeddedDocumentListField(School)
```

Feeding documents:

```py
user = User.objects.create(first_name="Rohit", last_name="Khatri")
user.schools = [
    School(name="Auden High School")),
    School(name="Baldwin Boys High School"),
    School(name="Baldwin Girls High School"),
    School(name="Aukamm Elementary School"),
    School(name="Mason-Rice Elementary")
]
user.save()

user = User.objects.create(first_name="ABC", last_name="DEF")
user.schools = [
    School(name="Little Harbor Elementary School")),
    School(name="Aukamm Elementary School"),
    School(name="Mason-Rice Elementary")
]
user.save()
```

I'm using this code the retrieve the `users` who have a particular school in their `schools` field:

```py
users = User.objects(school__match={"name": "Aukamm Elementary School"})
```

I want to get only the selected school which is `Aukamm Elementary School` in the schools field.

**Receiving**

```py
[
    {
        "first_name": "Rohit",
        "last_name": "Khatri",
        "schools": [
            {
                "name": "Auden High School"
            },
            {
                "name": "Baldwin Boys High School"
            },
            {
                "name": "Baldwin Girls High School"
            },
            {
                "name": "Aukamm Elementary School"
            },
            {
                "name": "Mason-Rice Elementary"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "first_name": "ABC",
        "last_name": "DEF",
        "schools": [
            {
                "name": "Little Harbor Elementary School"
            },
            {
                "name": "Aukamm Elementary School"
            },
            {
                "name": "Mason-Rice Elementary"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**Required Output**

```py
[
    {
        "first_name": "Rohit",
        "last_name": "Khatri",
        "schools": [
            {
                "name": "Aukamm Elementary School"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "first_name": "ABC",
        "last_name": "DEF",
        "schools": [
            {
                "name": "Aukamm Elementary School"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **[`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#exp._S_filter)** operator in the **[`aggregate`](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.aggregate)** function as

```
users = User.objects(school__match={ "name": "Aukamm Elementary School" }).aggregate(
    { "$project": {
        "first_name": 1,
        "last_name": 1,
        "schools": {
             "$filter": {
                  "input": "$schools",
                  "as": "school",
                  "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$school.name", "Aukamm Elementary School" ] }
             }
        }
    } }
)
```